# Plotting map for UK, in ggmap & ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

All,

if

```
Germany = map_bounds <- c(left = 5, bottom = 47, right = 16, top = 56)
```

what is the UK?

UK =

Comment: Don't those look like degrees E and degrees N?

Comment: how do i fix the map on to the UK, there must be an easier way than guessing co-ordinates

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these options:

```
library(maps)       
library(mapdata)    
#Option 1
map('worldHires',
    c('UK', 'Ireland', 'Isle of Man','Isle of Wight'),
    xlim=c(-11,3), ylim=c(49,60.9))
```

Output:

[image]

Or:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
#Data
worldmap = map_data('world')
#Option 2
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = worldmap, 
                        aes(x = long, 
                            y = lat, 
                            group = group,
                            ),
                        fill = 'gray90', 
                        color = 'black') + 
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-10,3), 
              ylim = c(50.3, 59))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Also, how do you make this polygon have alpha value of 0.4? 

coords.map <- coords.map + stat_density2d(data=coords.data, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, fill=..level.., alpha=..level..), geom="polygon")

Comment: The aspect ratio of the ggplot2 map looks completely wrong - how do you specify the correct aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Duck 's answer you can get the WGS84 (i.e. Longitude and Latitude) bounds of any country by searching for that country on [epsg.io](https://epsg.io).

The UK, for example, uses [British National Grid (EPSG 27700)](https://epsg.io/27700) so if you select that projection is gives you WGS84 bounds that you can use for your map bounds.

```
WGS84 bounds:
-8.82 49.79
1.92 60.94
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help above here is the nearly complete code, i just need to understand which bit, and how, to mod the heatmap polygons to be transparent, they're currently obstructing the map beneath.

library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(RColorBrewer)

coords.data <- read.csv(file="~/Desktop/locations.csv”)

-UK bounds
map_bounds <- c(left = -2.5, bottom = 51, right = 1.5, top = 54)

coords.map <- get_stamenmap(map_bounds, zoom = 10, maptype = "toner-lite”)

coords.map <- ggmap(coords.map, extent="device", legend="none”)

-heat map layer: Polygons with fill color based on relative frequency of coordinates
coords.map <- coords.map + stat_density2d(data=coords.data, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, fill=..level.., alpha=..level..), geom="polygon”)

-fill the density contours
coords.map <- coords.map + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(7, "Spectral")))

-Add the coords,color red and define shape
-Shapes: http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape

coords.map <- coords.map + geom_point(data=coords.data, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), fill="red", shape=23, alpha=0.4)

coords.map <- coords.map + theme_bw()
ggsave(filename="./coords.png")